# Permission error on user management

Tags: kibana, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

We just set up elasticsearch, logstash and kibana on our swisscom application cloud instance. Now when I log in into kibana with the full_access_username and full_access_password I can do almost everything except adding new users and manage existing ones under settings - user management.

There I always get a message saying:
**You do not have permission to manage users. Please contact your administrator.**

Does anyone of you has an idea on how to fix that?

We d like to have different users and give them permissions on some indices and attributes only.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Swisscom provides their Elasticsearch Service as managed, you have some limitations in terms of administrative functions. At the time of writing this includes cluster and user management as well as watches.
You can provide new users by creating service-keys `cf create-service-key <service-instance-name> <service-key-name>`.